# Comparing Arabic letters with double diacritics

Tags: c#, winforms, arabic

The Arabic language have diacritics similar to other foreign languages like Hebrew or Romanian but i am not sure if the same issue with Arabic applies to these languages.

In Arabic, a letter can have a double diacritic and that is the source of my problem.

[image]
[image]

As you can see form the images above, the outcome of both are the same but when comparing strings together, they don't match.

I could just check if both string Contains all characters but i am hoping for a better solution as this change will cause a lot of changes in my application.

Comment: what method are you using to compare?

Comment: normal string comparison "=="

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `==`, use `String.Equals(string1, string2, StringComparison. CurrentCulture)` as long as your current culture is Arabic. `==` works on the raw chars and does not account for the culture.

Comment: So in case i am using the default English culture, i have to use string.Compare()  and specify the Arabic culture ?

Comment: @ykh yup that is what i would do.